# This in Datum() of d3 version 4 cannot access the bound element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Refer to [Inline Labels](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4b66c0d9be9a0d56484e) in d3 v4.0.0-alpha 9,

```
label.append("rect", "text")
  .datum(() => this.nextSibling.getBBox())
  .attr('x', d => (d.x - labelPadding))
  .attr('y', d => (d.y - labelPadding))
  .attr('width', d => (d.width + (2 * labelPadding)))
  .attr('height', d => (d.height + (2 * labelPadding)));
```

It will append a rect to text by access the element inside the datum() via **this**.

> A label is rendered for each point in each series. Beneath this label, a white rectangle is added, whose size and position is computed automatically using element.getBBox plus a little bit of padding. The resulting label is thus legible

According to [D3 v3 set datum](https://bl.ocks.org/kenpenn/c13d62dd437b5eb8bd76df9828adc3db), we should create a new selection that's not bound to the data for later use in version 4 (eg. v4.7.4). I tried to create the new selection like following, but seem like the bbox is single object instead of multiple object should be loop through in datum as above code in d3 v4.0.0-alpha 9.

```
const newText = label.selectAll('text');
const bbox = newText.node().getBBox();

label.append('rect', 'text')
    .datum(() => bbox)
    .attr('x', d => (d.x - labelPadding))
    .attr('y', d => (d.y - labelPadding))
    .attr('width', d => (d.width + (2 * labelPadding)))
    .attr('height', d => (d.height + (2 * labelPadding)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet is not working for a simple reason. But, before addressing that, some considerations about your question:

- That code from Bostock (Inline Labels) uses D3 **v4**, not v3.
- `append("rect", "text")` does not append rectangles to texts. It append rectangles to the container, be it a SVG or a group element (in this particular case, a group), **before** the texts.

That last bullet point is important, because the texts will be always the `nextSiblings` in relation to the rectangles.

That being said, we come to your snippet. When you do this:

```
const newText = label.selectAll('text');
const bbox = newText.node().getBBox();
```

You are actually doing just this:

```
const bbox = label.selectAll('text').node().getBBox();
```

And your `datum` function will end up being:

```
.datum(() => label.selectAll('text').node().getBBox();)
```

Well, that is substantially different from Bostock's code, since this...

```
label.selectAll('text').node()
```

... will select all `text` elements but will return only to the **first one** in the DOM. That happens because of `node()`, which:

> Returns the **first** (non-null) element in this selection. (emphasis mine)

On the other hand, in Bostock's code, this...

```
.datum(() => this.nextSibling.getBBox())
```

... will point to a different DOM element at each iteration, because `this.nextSibling` will be a different `text` element every time (which, as we just saw in the beginning of this answer, is the `nextSibling` of the corresponding rectangle).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, *this* still point to the bound element in datum() at version of v4.0.0-alpha.9 but not the v4.7.4, may I know how get I get the same functionality of datum in v4.0.0-alpha.9 to datum in v4.7.4? It always give me error about cannot getBBox() from null object. thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `datum` function, which is the same. If you're using v4.7, use `insert` instead of `append`, because the texts have to be the **next** siblings of the rects. Here is the blocks using v4.7: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/a55daaaeffa8de6fc271157014695d3a

Comment: Yes, your example shows me what I need. after I replace the `append` with `insert`, I found that it still not working until I replace the line of `.datum(() => this.nextSibling.getBBox())` to `.datum(function () { return this.nextSibling.getBBox(); })`. It seem like arrow function in datum is not working as what I expected. `this` in arrow function is null object. Can you clear me this doubt? thank you.